# Retrieving data from python script using 'child-process' works in normal node.js script, but not in a required script

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, child-process, sys

I am making a node.js application where I need to send data to a python script where it preforms some calculations. Then I need to get the data from the python script back to a discord.js command-script `command.js`, that I run from the main script `index.js`.
I send the data i need to be calculated with the `child_process` module:

```
function func1(arg1, arg2){
    let spawn = require('child_process').spawn
    const pythonProcess = spawn('python',['t1.py', arg1, arg2]);
}
```

Then I retrieve and process the data in python with the `sys` module like this:

```
import sys

a = sys.argv[1]
b = sys.argv[2]

print(int(a) + int(b))
sys.stdout.flush()
```

After the data is handled in the python script `t1.py`, I retrieve it like this and try to log it (the problem is that it doesent log anything when I run the main script):

```
pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(Number(data))
});
```

I then send the resulting data from `command.js` to `index.js` using `module.exports`:

```
module.exports = {
    'func1': func1
}
```

Finally I `require` the function exported from the `command.js` script and run it in `main.js` while passing in two arguments:

```
let myFunction = require('./command-file/commands.js')
myFunction.func1(2, 2)
```

This does not work. I simply get no console.log() message at all in my terminal.
However. If I try to send the data to `t1.py` directly from `index.js` without sending the data to `command.js` first and not exporting the script, it works and returns '4' (Keep in mind I cannot do it this way because of how the rest of the application works, but that is irrelevant to this problem, I have to use `command.js`). My theory is that for some reason `child_process` doesent work with `module.exports`, but I dont know why...

Comment: Have edited my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structure:

```
.
├── index.js
└── script.py
```

index.js:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const command = spawn('python', ["./script.py", 1, 2]);

let result = '';

command.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  result += data.toString();
});
command.on('close', function (code) {
  console.log("RESULT: ", result);
});
```

script.py:

```
import sys

a = 0
b = 0

try:
  a = sys.argv[1]
  b = sys.argv[2]
except:
  print("DATA_MISSING")

sys.stdout.write("{}".format(int(a) + int(b)))
```

Start the code with node `index.js`